# How to copy int array value into byte array? only copy the value in C#

Tags: c#, integer, arrays

hi i have this kind of array

```
int[] arrayint = new int[32];
```

and it contains

```
arrayint[0] = 99
arrayint[1] = 121
arrayint[2] = 99
arrayint[3] = 66
...
```

is there a simple way to copy that integer array into a byte array like i want to make this byte array

```
byte[] streambit;
```

and it should be the same to the arrayint value

i want to be like this the output

```
streambit[0] = 99
streambit[1] = 121
streambit[2] = 99
streambit[3] = 66
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
streambit = arrayint.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

Just make sure that you have no value greater than 255.

Comment: You may like to add that no negative values should be there as well as corresponding byte will not be 'same' in that case...

Comment: An interesting thing to note here is that any integers greater than 255 or less than 0 will be converted in a wrapping fashion without throwing an overflow exception.  For example: -1 will convert to 255 and 256 will convert to 0.

Comment: that's it thank you very much... can you explain me about the code? i kind of confused about the meaning of i => (byte)i).ToArray() how does that make byte?

Comment: `i => (byte)i` is called a lambda expression, a special notation for an anonymous function. In this case, it's a function taking a parameter, converting it to int, then returning it. The `Select` method takes every element of the collection, then call the lambda on them. The `ToArray` method copies the result to an array.

Answer (score 2):

Without LINQ (useful when targeting .Net 2.0 for instance):

```
byte[] bytearray = Array.ConvertAll<int, byte>(arrayint, (z) => (byte)z);
```

---

Well yeah, much more faster than LINQ:

Test code (could be improved, but this gives an idea):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arrayint = new int[40000];

    arrayint[0] = 99;
    arrayint[1] = 157;
    arrayint[2] = 1;
    arrayint[3] = 45;

    byte[] bytearray;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        bytearray = Array.ConvertAll<int, byte>(arrayint, (z) => (byte)z);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("ConvertAll took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        bytearray = arrayint.Select(z => (byte)z).ToArray();
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("LINQ took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Result:

> ConvertAll took 1865 ms
>
> LINQ took 6073 ms

Comment: First time I hear of `Array.ConvertAll`. Seems indeed a better choice. When executing the Linq query, the results are stored in an internal buffer, then copied to an array. `Array.ConvertAll` directly allocates an array and makes the conversion during the copy. It probably explains the huge performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
streambit=arrayint.Where(x=>x>=0&&x<=255).Select(y=>(byte)y).ToArray();
```