# C# Inter class communication with extreme performance

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Suppose I want to publish an event from the `MarketDataProvider` class. The problem is that the event logic resides 2 level deeper.`MarketDataProvider` --> `Level1SocketClient` --> `Level1MessageHandler`.

In short, I would like to raise the event from `Level1MessageHandler` that `MarketDataProvider` can publish. The performance here is critical because there are a lot of events generated. I would like to find a clean way of doing it without chaining events from each level.

Comment: Have you tried with just event chaining, seeing if it is going to be the/a bottleneck?

Comment: Do you need the multicast (multiple subscriber) functionality of events, or do you only have a single listener?

Comment: @dbc Single subscriber only from top to bottom.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes and on the profiling this represent significant time

Comment: What about giving these objects an interface with a method on it that can be called, giving the core level code direct access to the subscriber?

Comment: It [used to be that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) delegate calls were slower than interface calls, but that might not be true any more.  See here: [Improving Reflection Performance with Delegates](http://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/01/improving-reflection-performance-with.html)

Comment: maybe it's worth a try: have you thought about Observables? You can pass them around as first-class objects and they are more or less events with a nicer unsubscribe-mechanic

Comment: So you are worrying about one additional delegate call when you are dealing with sockets at the same time? Are you sure this is even remotely relevant?

Comment: @usr I just questioning my design if there are a better way of doing it instead of multi level chaining.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen any code example please?

Comment: Uhm, declare an interface with the method, implement it in the outside code, pass the interface down to the inner object and store it there. Since I don't know if this will be a good enough answer I can't really leave an answer here, but then perhaps this question can't get good answers, only spark ideas.

Comment: Also, using Linq (and anonymous delegates) for extremely simple things in tight loops can bite you.  See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195729/how-to-copy-int-array-value-into-byte-array-only-copy-the-value-in-c-sharp/12195995#12195995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having an Event itself, could the intermediate class just pass the Add and Remove calls on to the lowest level class?  I.e.

```
public class Level1MessageHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;
}

public class Level1SocketClient
{
    Level1MessageHandler level1Handler;

    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived 
    {
        add 
        {
            level1Handler.MessageReceived += value;
        }
        remove 
        {
            level1Handler.MessageReceived -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

This would at least cut out one level of delegate call.

(Or did I get the direction of invocation reversed?  Anyway I think the idea is clear.)

**Update**

An interesting question arises: what happens if the intermediate listener needs to be disposable, and when disposed, remove all the events added through it?  You can do it by recording the events added in a local event, like so:

```
public interface IMessagePublisher<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<TEventArgs> MessageReceived;
}

public class MessageRePublisher<TEventArgs> : IMessagePublisher<TEventArgs>, IDisposable where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    readonly IMessagePublisher<TEventArgs> publisher;

    public MessageRePublisher(IMessagePublisher<TEventArgs> publisher)
    {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    EventHandler<TEventArgs> messageReceivedEventsAdded = null;

    public event EventHandler<TEventArgs> MessageReceived 
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add 
        {
            // events are multicast delegates, which are immutable.  We need to remove the previous
            // combined event, create a new combined event, then added that.
            // More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx
            if (messageReceivedEventsAdded != null)
                publisher.MessageReceived -= messageReceivedEventsAdded;
            messageReceivedEventsAdded += value;
            if (messageReceivedEventsAdded != null)
                publisher.MessageReceived += messageReceivedEventsAdded;
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove 
        {
            if (messageReceivedEventsAdded != null)
                publisher.MessageReceived -= messageReceivedEventsAdded;
            messageReceivedEventsAdded -= value;
            if (messageReceivedEventsAdded != null)
                publisher.MessageReceived += messageReceivedEventsAdded;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (messageReceivedEventsAdded != null && publisher != null)
            {
                publisher.MessageReceived -= messageReceivedEventsAdded;
            }
        }
        messageReceivedEventsAdded = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The intermediate listener combines all its events into a single concatenated event, then adds and removes that every time.